# Copy protection on a webpage : dashes

Tags: html, encoding, copy-paste, copy-protection

Here is a amazing webpage : [Go there](http://www.archivistes.org/Comment-former-et-sensibiliser-aux,1450)

Now, copy a part of the text, for instance, this block :[image: text on the website]

And now, paste-it on Notepadd++ (others editor seems not to work for that).  Here is a screenshot of the result :[image: same text pasted on Notepadd++]

How is this possible? Are there any dashes which cannot be printed on a webpage, but copy-able? I have heard about Copy Protection with JS, but here, I am very surprised...

Any idea about how this is implemented?

Comment: The page is using [Soft hyphens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen). They don't render on screen.

Comment: @SalmanA, make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Soft-Hyphen, an hyphenation authorization.
To remove it, try:

```
strtr($text, array("\xC2\xAD" => "")); // If you are in UTF-8
strtr($text, array("\xAD" => "")); // ISO 8859-1
str_replace('&shy;', '', $text); // html
```

Let's see in OpenOffice:[image]

Answer (score 2):

The page is using [Soft hyphens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen):

> In computing and typesetting, a soft hyphen (U+00AD soft hyphen, HTML:
>   `&#173;` `&shy;`), also called a discretionary hyphen or optional hyphen,
>   is a kind of hyphen used to specify a place in text where a hyphenated
>   break is allowed without forcing a line break in an inconvenient place
>   if the text is re-flowed.

The soft hyphen will not display unless the browser decides to break the line at that character.